# Ensuring there is always a platform for player to jump on

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am making a game where the player has to jump on platforms. However i am having a problem ensuring that there is always a tile for the player to step on. I created platforms this way:

```
p1 = Platforms(random.randint(0, 200), -100)
p2 = Platforms(random.randint(200, 400),-250)
p3 = Platforms(random.randint(400, 600),-600)
p4 = Platforms(random.randint(600, 800),-400)
p5 = Platforms(random.randint(800, 1000),-500)
p6 = Platforms(random.randint(800, 1000),-300)
```

`random.randint(n, n)` is the `x` position of the player and the numbers after comma is the `y` position of the player. How can i ensure that there is atleast 4 platforms on the screen withn 300 x-distance and 200 y-distance of each other (since my window size is 1200, 600) while also giving an impression that they are random and not not always in the same position. Thanks

Also here is my platform class for any references needed:

```
class Platforms:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 20
        self.speed_list = [0.5, 0.8, 1]


    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (3, 124, 23), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def move(self):
        self.y += random.choice(self.speed_list)

    def reset(self):
        if p1.y > 600:
            p1.y = -100 
            p1.x =  random.randint(0, 200)
        if p2.y > 600:
            p2.y = -250
            p2.x = random.randint(200, 400)
        if p3.y > 600:
            p3.y = -600
            p3.x = random.randint(400, 600)
        if p4.y > 600:
            p4.y = -400
            p4.x = random.randint(600, 800)
        if p5.y > 600:
            p5.y = -500
            p5.x = random.randint(800, 1000)
        if p6.y > 600:
            p6.y = -300
            p6.x = random.randint(800, 1000)


    def on_plat(self):
        for plat in g.platlist:
            if (b.x > plat.x) and (b.x < plat.x + plat.width) or (b.x + b.side > plat.x) and (b.x + b.side < plat.x + plat.width):
                if (b.y > plat.y) and (b.y < plat.y + plat.height) or (b.y + b.side > plat.y) and (b.y + b.side < plat.y + plat.height):
                    b.is_jumping = False
                    b.y =  plat.y - b.side

p1 = Platforms(random.randint(0, 200), -100)
p2 = Platforms(random.randint(200, 400),-250)
p3 = Platforms(random.randint(400, 600),-600)
p4 = Platforms(random.randint(600, 800),-400)
p5 = Platforms(random.randint(800, 1000),-500)
p6 = Platforms(random.randint(800, 1000),-300)

g.platlist = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]

while True: 
        for plats in g.platlist:
            plats.draw()
            plats.move()
            plats.reset()
            plats.on_plat()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a `Platform` class instead of a `Platforms` class? Currently, what happens if we decide that we want 15 platforms in total?

Comment: @AMC Even though i named it Platfroms, it has all the properties of a platform. I know the question has already been answered but  if we decided that we want 15 platforms, we could use a for loop to append 15 platforms in the list, which is why i passed x and y to the __init__ function so that they can be the only variables withn the properties of platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple workaround is to make a loop and take the last plateform position.

Something like:

```py
platforms = []
for i in range(6):
  x, y = 0, 0
  if (i > 0):
    lastplatform = platforms[i - 1]
    x, y = platforms[i - 1].x, platforms[i - 1].y
  x += random.randint(0, 200)
  y += random.randint(-100, 100)
  platforms.append(Platforms(x, y))
```

You can make additional check to prevent your plateform being vertically out of screen by changing the range of the y random number generation.

Comment: Can you validate my answer if it helps :)

Comment: Hi, i am having trouble understanding the code. Do you mind explaining what  lines 4, 5 and 6 do ? It would be helpful:)

Comment: According to my understanding, the for range starts from 1 and increases up until 6, so wouldnt  " i " always be greater than 0 in line 4? I am confused

Comment: Range iterate from 0 to x - 1. So it gives you: 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: The line 4 check if it's the first iteration.

The line 5 get the last platform, it's at index i - 1 because when you append an element to an array, the element is added at the end of the array.

The line 6, you take the last position of the last platforms.